# How does assigning a variable in a functions parameters work? What is the purpose of doing this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web

I've been trying to find docs for this but having no luck.

In ReactJS why do we set the state variable in the functions param? I've never seen anything like this before.

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) =>{
    switch(action.type){
        case "BUY_CAKE": return{
            ...state,
            numOfCakes: state.numOfCakes - 1
        }
        case "BUY_ICECREAM": return{
            ...state,
            numOfIceCreams: state.numOfIceCreams - 1
        }

        default: return state
    }
}
```

Why cant we just pass in initialState directly?

```
const reducer = (initialState, action) =>{
```

Comment: that's a default value for if you don't provide the param. so reducer() just returns the state

Comment: Function parameters in the function definition do declare variables, but the values come from the function _call_. But what if you don't pass a parameter? Well, that's what default parameters do: they give the value if the value you passed when you called the function was `undefined`.

Comment: Interesting to note, the syntax for function arguments is the same as Array Destructuring assignment: `let [first, second, third = "there was no third] = ['this is first', 'this is second']`. Run that and see what you get for the values of `first`, `second`, and `third`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters

Default parameter syntax.

That's a default value of initialState, if you don't provide the first parameter, so that  the return of calling `reducer() => initialState` (reducer() with no parameters just returns initialState).